# Maven Release Plugin: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, release, sax

As of recently our Ci jobs blows up into my face when executing the *release:prepare* goal of the Maven release plugin. I get a weird SAX parse error:
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(XMLScanner.java:746)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1014)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(XMLScanner.java:714)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:907)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
build   25-Sep-2019 13:42:25        at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:453)`

Even though i can `mvn clean install` the project just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out one of the submodules had a newline at the beginning of the pom.xml. Maven itself apparently did not care about this, but the maven release plugin could not parse this and blew up on me.